# Centering a paragraph which has 2 different font sizes

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a paragraph class with a span style inside, where the span class has a different-sized font and is causing my paragraph class not to center fully as it is slightly too far to the right (I'm pretty sure this is the reason). Here is my HTML:

```
<p class="priceWrap"><span class="moneySign">$</span>60000.50</p>
```

and here is my CSS:

```
.priceWrap {
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;

.moneySign{
font-size: 14px;
vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/M4hCS/3/. I could see it was center, what wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it seems pretty OK, or at least I dont get the real problem.
Take a look at the fiddle

[--> The fiddle <--](http://fiddle.jshell.net/A4Hb9/)

I realized you had a missing } for your .priceWrap, maybe thats what cause your issues.

Answer (score 0):

you have close .priceWrap class

```
<style>
    .priceWrap {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    }

   .moneySign{
   font-size: 140px;
   vertical-align: text-top;
   color:red;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: That was a typo sorry! Any advice??

Comment: just add line-height: 25px; in moneySign class

Answer (score 0):

You must use

```
 line-height
```

for your child element:

```
.moneySign{

 line-height: 20px;
 font-size: 10px;
 vertical-align: text-top;
 }
```

Now you will get dollar sign centered vertically, at half of the height of the paragraph

http://jsfiddle.net/kul_mi/vqC9Q/  - working example

Answer (score 0):

I have increased the size so that you can see that the text are Center aligned.

```
<style>
    .priceWrap {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 100px;
    }

    .moneySign{
        font-size: 15px;
        color:red;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>
```